# count total even and odd number between 20-50 with mysqll procedure

Tags: mysql, for-loop, stored-procedures

i'm having hard time with my homework , because im beginner using mysql procedure.
to search total numbers odd and even between 20-50 with looping.
i want to make output like this using mysql procedure to call: 
total_odd_numbers :15
total_even_numbers:16

i tried for sum up for even numbers like this :

```
`DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `genap`()
BEGIN
DECLARE x  INT;
DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
declare total int;

SET x = 20;
SET str =  '';
set total = 0;

 loop_label:  LOOP
 IF  x = 50  THEN 
 LEAVE  loop_label;
 END  IF;
             SET  x =x+1;

 IF  (x mod 2) THEN
 ITERATE  loop_label;


 ELSE
                SET  str = CONCAT(str,x,',');
                SET total= total+x;
 END  IF;
         END LOOP;    
         SELECT sum(total);

 END`
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried yet. SO is not a place for spoon feeding.

Comment: @SarangK if you dont want to answer just passed it,, easy

Comment: @Strawberry no,, just need looping method, i copied from my sql editor

Comment: @Strawberry count number of odd and even numbers between 20-50 using mysql stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ShowOddEvesBetween;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowOddEvesBetween(IN fromNum INT, IN toNum INT)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE odds INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE evens INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE x INT;

 SET x = fromNum;

 WHILE x <= toNum DO
  IF x % 2 THEN
   SET odds = odds + 1;
  ELSE
   SET evens = evens + 1;
  END IF;

  SET x = x + 1;
 END WHILE;

 SELECT CONCAT("total_odd_numbers: ", odds, ", total_even_numbers: ", evens) AS "Odds & Evens";

 END;
;;
```

Then call it

```
CALL ShowOddEvesBetween(20, 50);
```

Will output what you want

```
MariaDB [test]> CALL ShowOddEvesBetween(20, 50);
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Odds & Evens                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| total_odd_numbers: 15, total_even_numbers: 16 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Mei_R you get that error after you call it? Can you paste or update your answer with the full error?